Derivative of smoothed data in python
I have the problem to take the derivative of some experimental data. I tried to smooth the data I got because the original derivative made no sense to me. I attached a picture with my experimental data and a theoretical curve how the data should look like. Then I took the derivative of the experimental and the theoretical data for comparison.
This is my current code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

bias = pd.read_csv('bias_voltage_2024_12_12__13_17_47.csv', delimiter=',',         header=None)
data1 = pd.read_csv('sipm_dark_DD_microfc_v1_2024_12_12__14_57_27.csv', delimiter=',', header=None)

bias_voltage = bias[1][:425].values
dark_current = data1[1]

filt = np.ones(15)/15
smooth = np.convolve(dark_current, filt, 'valid')
deriv = np.gradient(smooth, bias_voltage[7:-7])

x = np.linspace(0, 32, 100)
mu = 25.4
y = np.where(x < mu, 0, 0.0002*(x - 8) * (x - mu))
deriv2 = np.gradient(y, x)

#plt.scatter(bias_voltage[7:-7], deriv, s=8, label='derivative')
plt.scatter(x, deriv2, s=8, label='theoretical data')
plt.xlabel('Bias Voltage (V)')
plt.ylabel('Current (A) / Derivative of Current (A/V)')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('theo_deriv.png')
plt.show()




The last image shows roughly how the derivative of the experimental data should look like . To smooth the data did not worj for me until now. Am I doing something wrong?
Here the link with the two csv files used in my example code:
experimental data files

Without the actual data, we cannot give you specific advice. But it looks like your data must have something going on at the beginning causing there to be large derivatives there which changes the scale of your plot. How does your derivative compare if you only plot the derivative data after 5 or 10 V?

Please provide the data as a [mre]

Thank you for your answers. I added a link to the files.

Because of the noise in the experimental data, I thought it would be easier to work with np.interp() to interpolate the data:
x = np.linspace(0, 32, 100)
interCurve = np.interp(x, bias_voltage, dark_current)
derivB = np.gradient(interCurve[:-1], x[:-1])

plt.plot(x, interCurve, label='interpolated curve')
plt.scatter(bias_voltage, dark_current, marker='x', color='g', s=6, label='experimental points')
plt.plot(x[:-1], derivB, label='derivative of interpolated curve')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


